# Konjunktiv in einem kausalen Nebensatz

Tags: word-order, subjunctive, modal-verb

Sind die beiden Formen korrekt?

> Etwas ist so, **weil sowas nicht hätte gemacht werden können.**
>   Etwas ist so, **weil sowas nicht gemacht werden gekonnt hätte.**

Wenn sie beide korrekt sind, sind sie ganz austauschbar?

Comment: Die Verneinung verändert hier die Sache nicht. Darum denke ich, dass du es aus der Frage ganz wegnehmen soll. Es verwirrt nur. Es sind doch die viele Hilfswerben die es schwierig macht, nicht die Verneinung. Eigentlich auch nicht der Konjunktiv, es wäre ja genau die gleiche Schwierigkeiten mit Indikativ.

Comment: @Beta Ich stimme zu. Die Verneinung im Titel hat Hubert Schölnast hinzugefügt, nicht ich. Ich habe zwar nichts besonderes auf Verneinung mit meiner Frage abgezielt.

Answer (score 1):

Dein zweiter Beispielsatz ruft in mir ein spontanes *Häh?* hervor. Was soll er überhaupt bedeuten?

(Das *nicht* ist im übrigen egal.)

---

Schreib zum Verständnis doch beides in Hauptsätze mit *denn* um.

> Etwas ist so. Denn sowas hätte gemacht werden können.
>
> Etwas ist so, weil sowas hätte gemacht werden können.

Beides identisch. Vergleiche einen einfacheren Satz:

> Etwas ist so. Denn es ist so.
>
> Etwas ist so, weil es so ist.

Hier findet also eine Bewegung des finiten Verbs von Position zwei ans Ende statt. Wieso nicht bei deinem ersten  Beispiel? Der Grund ist, dass das Ende in der Nebensatzvariante schon durch die Infinitive besetzt ist. Da bleibt für das finite Verb kein Platz. Ein Minimalbeispiel:

> Etwas ist so. Denn es hätte so sein können.
>
> Etwas ist so, weil es so hätte sein können.

Das finite Verb *hätte* landet in der Nebensatzvariante also direkt vor den anderen Infinitiven. Nehmen wir statt *sein* mal so wie in deinem Beispiel *gemacht werden*:

> Etwas ist so. Denn es hätte so gemacht werden können.
>
> Etwas ist so, weil es so hätte gemacht werden können.

---

Nun dein zweites Beispiel. Was hat das finite Verb *gekonnt hätte* am Schluss des Satzes zu suchen?

> Etwas ist so, weil sowas gemacht werden gekonnt hätte.

Als Hauptsatz umformuliert müsste es zur Position zwei rücken:

> Etwas ist so. Denn sowas hätte gemacht werden **gekonnt**.

An dem Partizip **gekonnt** sehen wir, dass es sich um einen Dialektsprecher aus Bayern oder Österreich handelt, denn dort wird der *Ersatzinfinitiv* nicht benutzt. Standardsprachlich muss er dort aber hin:

> Etwas ist so. Denn sowas hätte gemacht werden können.

Dies ist exakt derselbe Satz wie ganz oben.

Die Antwort ist also: Ja, beide Sätze bedeuten dasselbe, allerdings stammt dein zweiter Beispielsatz von einem Dialektsprecher, der den Ersatzinfinitiv nicht verwendet.

Comment: Danke. Allerdings, es tut mir Leid dass du so viel Mühe gegeben hast, um es zu erklären dass es keinen Unterschied zwischen "'weil" und "Denn", oder gar Verneigung, in diesem Zusammenhang ergibt. Der @Hubert Schölnast hat die Inhalt und Titel meiner Frage verändert, und hat sie auf irrelevante und ungewollte Hinsichten abgezielt. \:

Comment: Es ist auch egal, ob im Nebensatz nun der Indikativ oder der Konjunktiv verwendet wird. Der Unterschied zwischen deinen beiden Beispielsätzen liegt nur in der Verwendung des Ersatzinfinitivs.

Comment: Auch eine Frage die mir eingefallen ist: zwischen a. "...weil ich es hätte nicht machen können", und b. "...weil ich es nicht hätte machen können", gibt es einen Unterschied, oder ist es egal ob der Verneigung vor oder nach dem "hätte" sich befindet?

Comment: Nein, es ist nicht egal. *Weil ich es hätte nicht machen können, aber dennoch machte.* – *Weil ich es nicht hätte machen können. Tut mir leid, es ging wirklich nicht.*

Comment: Schön! Ich habe es jetzt vollkommen verstanden :)

Comment: Moment mal, aber wenn ich sagen will: "I couldn't have done it", dann dieser Logik nach, soll es "ich hätte es machen nicht können" sein, und nicht "Ich hätte es nicht machen können", was mir als richtiger scheint. Stimmt das?

Comment: Nein. Im Deutschen immer genau der Satzteil durch das *nicht* verneint, der dem *nicht* folgt. Die einzige Ausnahme davon ist ein Verb in Position 2. In diesem Fall wandert das *nicht* ganz ans Ende des Hauptsatzes.

Comment: Jetzt muss ich fragen, wenn ich es eigentlich ausdrücken möchte, dass ich die möglichkeit hatte, etwas nicht zu tun, wie wurde ich das sagen, denn "Ich hätte es nicht machen können" verneint das "können", und nicht das "machen".

Answer (score 0):

> #### Sind die beiden Formen korrekt?

Ja, beide Beispiele sind grammatikalisch korrekt.

> weil sowas nicht gemacht werden gekonnt hätte.

In der Satire<sup>1</sup> hätte so eine Formulierung durchaus ihren Platz hätte gekonnt haben.

Für die *"normale"* (Schrift- / Umgangssprache) ist so eine Formulierung schlicht *unüblich*.
Man würde sagen

> weil sowas nicht hätte gemacht werden können.

---

> Wenn sie beide grammatisch sind, sind sie ganz austauschbar?

Was die Grammatik betrifft, bezieht sich *hätte* im ersten Beispiel auf *gemacht*, und im zweiten auf *gekonnt*.
Rein abstrakt besehen von den *Subjekten* her besehen, sind beide Sätze **nicht** zu 100% austauschbar.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>**Allgemein:** Literarischer/Dramaturgischer Kontext.</sub>

Comment: Bedeutet jeder Satz etwas anderes? Es sollte die Bedeutung von: "Because something like that could not have been done" haben. Soll der erste Satz so formuliert werden:
"weil sowas nicht hätte können gemacht werden." ?

Comment: @sermonionx _"Bedeutet jeder Satz etwas anderes?"_ Oberflächlich betrachtet nicht. Aus der 2. Formulierung kann man jedoch einen subtilen Kontext wegen des Subjektbezugs herauslesen. Wie gesagt, würde man umgangssprachlich diese Formulierung eher nicht wählen.

Comment: Auch in Gedichten/Büchern ist die 2. Formulierung nicht zu finden?

Comment: @sermonionx _"Auch in Gedichten/Büchern ist die 2. Formulierung nicht zu finden?_ Das überrascht mich nicht. Dennoch ist diese Formulierung prinzipiell grammatikalisch korrekt.

Comment: Übrigens, ich habe deinen Satz nicht verstanden:
"In der Satire hätte so eine Formulierung durchaus seinen Platz hätte gekonnt haben."; Warum gibt es zwei "hätte"? Es hat mich wirklich verwirrt. Kannst du das mir erklären?

Comment: @sermonionx Das wäre dann futur II gwesen ...

Comment: Soll die futur 2 das Verb "werden" nicht irgendwo enthalten?